# How many Teamviewers assigned devices (registered at my teamviewer account) can I have?

Tags: teamviewer

I currently have 6 users assigned to my Teamviewer account. Can I add as much (more) users as I want?
I typically may want to connect to 3 devices at once... but I am asking about the limit of registered/assigned devices (in general) to my account.

Comment: Best to ask directly to TeamViewer as it will depends on your license (what you have paid for).

Comment: Can you please give me an estimation? I didn't pay for anything.. and I need to know simply if I am safe to add one more device to the account (I am not interested in managing (working with) more than 3 devices at once. I just need to know about including one more device to the account..

Comment: We are jot TeamViewer. We cannot answer this question.